# RabbitMQ receiver not quitting

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a basic doubt about rabbitMQ. I read a sample program in https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

```
  public class Recv {

  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    **Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel()**;

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

  }
}
```

It says that we should not use a try-with-resource statement to automatically close the channel and the connection but instead we should write as it is given.

But my doubt is why the program is not exiting after executing **System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");**, I could not see a wait/while loop  in the code.

I know that I am missing some basic info but I could not find out that yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Program did not close automatically as RabbitMQ is running tasks Asynchronously.
The `Connection` and `Channel` are open.

It's because we did not use "try-with-resource statement". Without it, we need to close connection and channel manually.

Quoting the Page you mentioned: [RabbitMQ Tutorial 1: Java](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html)

In case of a Publisher:

> We can use a try-with-resources statement because both `Connection` and `Channel` implement `java.io.Closeable`. This way we don't need to close them explicitly in our code

Receiver(**Applies to class in Question here**):

> Why don't we use a try-with-resource statement to automatically close the channel and the connection? By doing so we would simply make the program move on, close everything, and exit! This would be awkward because we want the process to stay alive while the consumer is listening asynchronously for messages to arrive.

Edit: Adding reference for my comment on this answer: [java-daemon-thread](https://www.baeldung.com/java-daemon-thread)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The part which is not clear to me is there should be some part in the library which make the the process for waiting , right?  I am looking for that part. Similarly the  parts which says connection is closed therefore you should not wait any more

Comment: @nantitv I don't think there would be a method specifically written to make execution wait. A Java program exits when the last non-daemon thread is finished or you call System exit().

Comment: @prashanthI did go through some parts of the RabitMQ source code and understood how it's happening. It's in com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection. There is a MainLoop thread which loops until shutdown.                while (_running) {
                    Frame frame = _frameHandler.readFrame();
                    readFrame(frame);
                }. With autclosable, in the close () method, we are closing the above connection which cause the shutdown